# Distinctness of solutions to a determinant equation.

Tags: matrices, determinant

Lets say I have a matrix A with constants x and paramater Y in the following form:

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    Y & x_{12} & x_{13}  \\
    x_{12} & Y & x_{23}  \\
    x_{13} & x_{23} & Y 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I know that if all x are the same, then $\det[A] = 0$ has only one solution for Y.

My proof here is to directly compute the determinant, and then solve the suppressed cubic.

I want to also prove that if not all x are the same, that det[A]=0 has 3 distinct solutions. This is slightly more than just the converse. Directly computing is very painful, and I was able to show it only with Mathematica.

My question is how to justify these two statements more elegantly.

Comment: I disagree with your first conclusion.  If all $x_{ij} = 1$ for instance, then we end up with the solutions $Y = 1,-2$.

Comment: In any case, your question is equivalent to asking about the multiplicity of the [eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) of the matrix 
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&x_{12} & x_{13}\\x_{12}&0&x_{23}\\x_{13}&x_{23}&0}
$$

Comment: An example of a matrix where $\det(A) = 0$ fails to have distinct solutions:
$$
A = \pmatrix{Y&2&3\\4&Y&12\\5&10&Y}
$$

Comment: Please note that the proposed matrix $A$ is symmetric! This means your conterexample isn't one.

Answer (score 3):

Your first proposition is generally incorrect. If $x_{12}=x_{13}=x_{23}=x$, then both $Y_{1,2}=x$ and $Y_3=-2x$ are solutions of $\det[A]=0$. Those are different for $x \neq0$. In that case, the first solution has algebraic and geometric multiplicity $2$, the second algebraic and geometric multiplicity $1$.

ADDED after more thoughts about the second proposition:
The second proposition is true. It is easy to see that

$$\det[A]=f(Y)=Y^3 + 2x_{12}x_{13}x_{23} - Y(x^2_{12} + x^2_{13} + x^2_{23})$$.

In order for $f(Y)=0$ to have a root with multiplicity > 1, it has to be also a root of $f'(Y)=0$, which means

$$f'(Y)=3Y^2-(x^2_{12} + x^2_{13} + x^2_{23})=0,$$

which implies

$$Y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{x^2_{12} + x^2_{13} + x^2_{23}}3}.$$

Putting this into $f(Y)=0$ we get

$$0 = f(Y)=Y(Y^2-(x^2_{12} + x^2_{13} + x^2_{23})) + 2x_{12}x_{13}x_{23}=-\frac23(x^2_{12} + x^2_{13} + x^2_{23})Y + 2x_{12}x_{13}x_{23}$$

which implies

$$x_{12}x_{13}x_{23} = \frac13(x^2_{12} + x^2_{13} + x^2_{23})Y.$$

Squaring both sides yields to

$$(x_{12}x_{13}x_{23})^2=\frac19(x^2_{12} + x^2_{13} + x^2_{23})^2Y^2 = \frac19(x^2_{12} + x^2_{13} + x^2_{23})^2\frac{x^2_{12} + x^2_{13} + x^2_{23}}3 =\frac1{27}(x^2_{12} + x^2_{13} + x^2_{23})^3$$

This is the same condition as Yves Daoust arrived in his answer.

Now if we assume that all the $x_{ij}$ are real numbers, then this condition indeed implies that all $x_{ij}$ must be the same. That's because, as every $x_{ij}$ appears squared, we can generally assume that all $x_{ij} \ge 0$. The one can apply the theorem of the inequality of quadratic and geometric mean:

$$\sqrt[3]{x_{12}x_{13}x_{23}} \le \sqrt\frac{x^2_{12} + x^2_{13} + x^2_{23}}{3}$$

Putting this inequality to the 6th power leads to

$$(x_{12}x_{13}x_{23})^2\le \frac1{27}(x^2_{12} + x^2_{13} + x^2_{23})^3$$

and we know that equality (as required for a solution for $Y$ with multiplicity > 1) only happens if $x_{12}=x_{13}=x_{23}$.

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial is

$$y^3-(x_{12}^2+x_{23}^2+x_{13}^2)y+2x_{12}x_{23}x_{13}.$$

The multiplicity of the roots is determined by the discriminant,

$$4p^3+27q^2\propto-(x_{12}^2+x_{23}^2+x_{13}^2)^3+27(x_{12}x_{23}x_{13})^2.$$